# Change timer output language

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to translate this timer into a German version:

```
setCountDown: function() {
    var e = this,
        t = new Date;
    e.secondsDiff = Math.floor((e.weddingDate.getTime() - t.getTime()) / 1e3);
    var n = 'in <span id="days"></span> ' + e.option.labels[0] + '  <span id="hours"></span> ' + e.option.labels[1] + '  <span id="minutes"></span> ' + e.option.labels[2] + '  <small><span id="seconds"></span> ' + e.option.labels[3] + "</small>";
    $("#timer").html(n)
},
```

My Problem is that I would like to have displayed instead of `days -> Tage`, `hours -> Stunden`, `minutes -> Minuten`, `seconds -> Sekunden`.

I simply tried to change the labels, but this gives me no output regarding the counter, because I guess the counter works only with the labels.

Any suggestions to use a simple solution for my function?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: *but this gives me an error.* But you don’t want to tell it us? What’s the logic behind this?

Comment: You forgot to post error.

Comment: Basically, I get no counter output...